# Insert statement runs twice

Tags: php, sql, pdo, insert

I am trying to build some sort of database class (all PDO). All my functions work up till now, but the insert statement runs twice. I really don't see where it goes wrong. When I run the code with some echoes in it, the echoes only appear once so I don't think that it actually gets executed twice...

When I use the `getBind` function with other statements it works perfectly fine so...

THE CODE

```
 function insert ($p_sTable, $p_aCol, $p_aVal) {

    $this->m_sQuery .= "INSERT INTO ".$p_sTable." (";

    $queryCols = "";
    foreach ($p_aCol as $col) { ... }

    $this->m_sQuery .= $queryCols.") VALUES (";

    $queryPlaceholders = "";
    foreach ($p_aCol as $placeholder) {... }

    foreach ($p_aVal as $p_aValtosave) { .... }


    $this->m_sQuery .= $queryPlaceholders.")";

    echo "m_sQuery:</br>".$this->m_sQuery;

    echo "</br>print bindCol</br>";
    print_r($this->m_aBindCol);

    echo "</br>print bindVal</br>";
    print_r($this->m_aBindVal);


    return $this;

}
```

WHERE I CALL THE FUNCTION:

```
$db = Db::getConnection();
$arr = $db->insert("geprutsvanlisa",["kolom1","kolom2"], ["24", "24"])->getBind();
```

> THE OUTPUT: m_sQuery:

```
INSERT INTO geprutsvanlisa (kolom1, kolom2) VALUES (:ikolom1, :ikolom2)
print bindCol
Array ( [0] => ikolom1 [1] => ikolom2 ) 
print bindVal
Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => 24 ) 
echo i:0
bindvalue(:ikolom1, 24) 
echo i:1
bindvalue(:ikolom2, 24)
```

echo this ms query

```
INSERT INTO geprutsvanlisa (kolom1, kolom2) VALUES   (:ikolom1, :ikolom2)
echo this bindcol Array ( [0] => ikolom1 [1] => ikolom2 ) 
echo this bindval Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => 24 )
```

Comment: Try changing the first line of your `insert` function to this: ` $this->m_sQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$p_sTable." (";`  (remove the `.=` append operator)

Comment: unfortunately it's still doing it twice. But thanks for the help!